# What happens to in-progress processes when a POS goes offline?

Tags: eve-online

I have set up a player owned structure with a pair of advanced mobile laboratories, these mobile laboratories are currently performing material efficiency research on some reasonably expensive blueprints for battleships so that I can later start producing these ships with the intention of selling them.

Currently the research process has more time remaining than the expected time remaining for the fuel left in the control tower. Obviously I'm about to put more fuel in, but I was wondering - what happens to any in-progress processes, be that researching or refining or construction or whatever - when the control tower for a player owned structure runs out of power and goes offline?

Do the processes fail? Are the materials lost? Or are the current in-progress processes preserved at their current state, waiting for the control tower to come back online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any jobs that are currently running will stop, and any progress made on the BPO during that job will also be lost (as will any materials supplied as part of the industry job).
You will need to refuel and online the POS again (along with the lab in question) in order to be able to retrieve your BPO.

(alternatively, some "helpful" player may help you out by War deccing you, and destroying your offlined POS - potentially claiming the BPO if it drops when the lab is destroyed - thus relieving you from having to worry about it any more)

NB. You only lose the progress of the job in operation when the POS goes offline - completed jobs remain completed, so only partial jobs are cancelled.

Comment: Partial jobs are not cancelled, they are paused.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you will probably be war decced to blow up your modules to see if anything valuable drops, though :) So it very much encourages aggression. However, all research is simply paused, as are manufacturing jobs, and as long as you online it without unanchoring anything, research/manufacturing will continue.

Comment: Nothing currently in an S&I job will drop, however, it will always be destroyed.